# Validate string with .match()

Tags: javascript

I'm validating various input data params.

I'm trying to figure out .match and RegExp.

This seems to validate if a string ONLY contains 0-9 characters:

```
!str.match(/^[0-9]+$/)
```

And fails if the string contains anything else.

Is that correctly understood, or does it simply check if the string contains any 0-9 characters?

So I can do:

```
if (!string.match(/^[0-9]+$/))
    console.log('fails as the string contains other characters than 0-9');
```

Comment: Why don't you just run the code and see what it does? Or read a regexp tutorial? Or paste it into a regexp checker such as regex101.com which will give you an English-like description of what it means?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, i would use something like this:

```js
string='188867899';
var regex = /\D/; //any non-digit character
if (regex.test(string)) //if string contains any non-digit char
console.log('String 1 contains non-digit chars');

string2='1888y67899';
var regex = /\D/; //any non-digit character
if (regex.test(string2)) //if string contains any non-digit char
console.log('String 2 contains non-digit chars');
```

but, that's matter of choice (taste, whatever), more or less...

Answer (score 0):

The [**match()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method retrieves the matches when matching a string against a regular expression.

Your regular expression is `/^[0-9]+$/` which means

`^` : asserts position at start of the string

`[0-9]` : a single character in the range between 0 (ASCII 48) and 9 (ASCII 57)

`+` : Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible

`$` : asserts position at the end of the string

The following code snippet is using the test() method to test for a match in a string.

```js
var regex = /^[0-9]+$/;

console.log(regex.test("0123")); //true only 0-9
console.log(regex.test("1")); //true only 0-9
console.log(regex.test("")); //false Not at least 1 character 0-9
console.log(regex.test("a0123")); //false contains a letter
console.log(regex.test("abc")); //false contains multiple letters
```

Comment: Your description describes `match`, then your examples use `test`.